How to access off-premise MySQL database server through Power Automate
I have a need to pull data from an on-premise AS/400 system and transfer it to an off-premise MySQL database automatically. I have been able to pull data from the AS/400 using an On-Premise Data Gateway with Power Automate. However, I am not show how (or if) I can get that data to the MySQL database using Power Automate. The MySQL database server is internet-facing with a public IP address.
If I try to make a Power Automate connection to the MySQL server, it wants me to select a Gateway. Since the MySQL server has a public IP, I am wondering if it is possible for this to work without needing a separate Gateway in the MySQL server's network.
Can I make a connection to the off-premise MySQL server using the Gateway I am already using for the on-premise AS/400, or would I need a separate Gateway in the same network as the off-premise MySQL server?
I haven't gotten too far into this, and am asking to try to learn what general direction to direct my efforts. Thank you!

You really should talk to tht power automate admins in your organisation as the answer depends on how your infrastructure is set up and configured. Requiring gateway for external access is an often used oattern in an organisation as it gives IT bigger control over what data is fed into power automate.

I am the Power Automate admin for the organization. I realize that an individual network's setup can introduce variables to complicate this, but generally speaking, are you saying that it is possible for the On-Premise Data Gateway to access an internet-facing server that is outside of the local LAN the Gateway is installed in?

Yes, it is possible.

Thanks for confirming. I did manage to get connected to the remote MySQL server using the same Gateway I used to connect to the on-premises AS/400. I appreciate you letting me know I was headed in the right direction by trying it that way.
